# Apache downloads php files instead processing them (after php 7 upgrade)

Tags: php, apache, centos, httpd.conf, php-7

I've got a set up with CentOS 7.2, Apache 2.4.6 and I had php 5.4 running on it. 
Now I wanted to upgrade my PHP version to 7 and hereby I followed the steps described in this article:

[How To Upgrade to PHP 7 on CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-centos-7)

```
curl 'https://setup.ius.io/' -o setup-ius.sh
sudo bash setup-ius.sh
sudo yum remove php-cli mod_php php-common
sudo yum install mod_php70u php70u-cli php70u-mysqlnd
sudo apachectl restart
```

It installed php 7 and I can use it to execute php code. `php -v` gives me:

```
PHP 7.0.9 (cli) (built: Aug 16 2016 10:01:52) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

When I access a php file with `<php phpinfo(); ?>` via apache it will ask me to download the file.

In my `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d` I have the following:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
  LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule !prefork.c>
  LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7-zts.so
</IfModule>
```

My virtual hosts in httpd.conf all have (and had in the old php5.4 situation), they have been automatically created by my Virtualmin set up:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php5
FCGIWrapper /home/myvhost/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php
FCGIWrapper /home/myvhost/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php5
```

The contents of `/home/myvhost/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi` are as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
PHPRC=$PWD/../etc/php5
export PHPRC
umask 022
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=99999
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS
SCRIPT_FILENAME=$PATH_TRANSLATED
export SCRIPT_FILENAME
exec /bin/php-cgi
```

I am not sure what could be the reason that php code is not properly handled by apache. I hope you can give me some ideas on how to solve/investigate it. I will be happy to provide more information on the set up if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a Handler not a media type. As in, for example:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Sidenote: Nowadays, unless you have compiled php for thread safety maybe you should be looking to use Apache 2.4 with mpm_event and mod_proxy_fcgi + php-fpm instead of "Apache 2.4 with prefork + mod_php".

Comment: I added your lines on the bottom of `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-php.conf` and restarted httpd. Unfortunately I do not see any difference in behavior.

Comment: Note that "files" mean nothing for Apache, context do. Are you sure that file is being loaded?, and in which context is that added? Add that in the appropiate virtualhost for example. And last, what are your requests like?

Comment: In `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` `
`IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf`. It picks up these conf files, if I remove some it will give me appropriate errors related to the ones that were removed. A request is like `http://myvhost.com/i.php`, it gives a 200 return code and a content type of "application/x-httpd-php" and the browser asks to download the file, which has all the php contents inside. The contents are valid and did work when run in the php5.4 set up.

Comment: in my virtualhost it has the following. As this still refers to php5, I wonder if it may be part of the problem: `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php5
FCGIWrapper /home/relovest/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php
FCGIWrapper /home/relovest/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php5`

Comment: So in one place you are loading mod_php module, in another you have a wrapper for mod_fcgid or similar. Quite a mess :), delete all this in your virtualhost and add what I told you also in the appropiate virtualhost, make sure there is nothing else assigning handlers or types since what I specified is the only thing you will need aside from loading the module.

Comment: also, do not misunderstand me. Using mod_fcgid is perfectly fine, but your post started mentioning you were loading mod_php, and that's the path I guided you to. Don't mix handlers for different methods, and if you get plain text instead of interpreted  php files you probably haven't loaded and set up mod_fcgid correctly either

Comment: I suppose I have to remove mod_php then (the tutorial followed was probably not suited for my set up). If I remove the `10-php.conf` with `<IfModule prefork.c>
  LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule !prefork.c>
  LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7-zts.so
</IfModule>` apache starts complaining about php_value and php_admin_value statements in my virtual host definitions however.

Comment: you are deviating from your original question.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that you are using webmin(virtualmin) and after installing php one file actualy has been modified, if you check `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf` you may see uncomented lines in it. 
At same time you may see `php.conf.rpmnew` that was older version with lines comented out, so just add `#` to each of line in that file or delete it and rename you older file `php.conf.rpmnew` into just `php.conf`
dont forget restart apache after that:

> apachectl restart